# What is the most basic way to show that $\emptyset \in S$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $S$ be a set, what is the most basic way to show that $\emptyset \in S$?

I am asking because sometimes a question in involving a topology $\tau$ or a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ will want you to show that $\emptyset$ is in $\tau$, $\Sigma$ etc. And most proofs glosses over this.

For example, let $\Sigma$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the half open sets $(a,b]$ How do we show that $\emptyset \in \Sigma$

Comment: In the example, you can simply set $a=b$.

Comment: Alternatively, we know that sigma-algebras are closed under finite differences, so $(1,2]\setminus (1,2]=\emptyset$ will be in $\Sigma$.

Comment: Often-times it will be clear or explicitly stated at the time of constructing $\tau$, for example the co-finite topology:  $\tau = \{A\subseteq X~:~A=\emptyset~\text{or}~|X\setminus A|<\infty\}$

Comment: For sigma-algebras we can also use the fact that they are closed under countable intersections. So in your example, take $(0,1] \cap (2,3] = \emptyset$. So $\emptyset \in \Sigma$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a general answer to this. It really just depends on the conditions you have on the thing that might be a topology or a $\sigma$-algebra. You just have to show that a set that contains no points fulfills those conditions. As [JMoravitz](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/179297/jmoravitz) says in the comments, it is often explicitly stated that the empty set has to be in a topology because otherwise the conditions wouldn't cover the empty set.